# Congratulations Text for "Known Bad" Reopen Queue Audits is Wrong

Tags: bug, review, review-audits, wording

On successfully passing a "known bad" audit in the Reopen Votes review queue (i.e., correctly voting to "Leave Closed"), we are presented with the following congratulatory banner:

[image]

However, the reviewer has *not* just voted to *close* the question but to  *leave it closed*. This is the *exact same* text displayed for successful audits in the Close Votes queue; in that case, though, it *is* correct, and it seems that the text has just been copied from one queue to the other.

Surely, the last sentence here should be along the lines of:

> Leaving closed is appropriate for questions with serious/unresolved problems.

Note that analogous text for "known good" audits in the Reopen Votes queue does correctly use the phrase, "Reopening."